# In Eclipse, how to NOT sort open file list alphabetically?

Tags: c++, eclipse, settings

There's a little "show list" button in the upper right corner at the end of the document tabs row. When clicked, it displays a drop down list of all open files.

In all my past experience with Eclipse, it's never sorted this drop down file list alphabetically. It's always displayed the open files in the order that their tabs appear horizontally. This made it easy for me to navigate, arranging related files near one another and knowing where they are located in the list.

Recently something changed to make that drop down list always sort alphabetically. I really hate this and it's slowing down the speed at which I switch between files (mainly when I'm working on one file and need to jump to one that's far away in the list).

Anyone know if there's some hidden setting that'll undo this sorting and revert it back to the default (unsorted)?

Eclipse version is Luna. Perspective is C/C++.

Comment: Wait. It is? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=439045

Comment: @nitind - It is still open. I think something fishy here. It doesn't sort in my case. I'm using Kepler I even tried in Luna.

Comment: @Brent212- in which perspective you are facing this problem???

Comment: C/C++ Perspective, Eclipse version is Luna.